# Logics in which bi-implication and equivalence comes apart

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic

Where $\phi, \psi$ are variables over formulas, are there logics for which we have either (or both) of $(1)$ and $(2)\thinspace$?

$$(1) \hspace{0.5cm}(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\hspace{0.3cm} \land \hspace{0.3cm} (\psi \rightarrow \phi)\hspace{0.3cm} \nvdash \hspace{0.3cm} \phi \hspace{0.3cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} \psi $$
$$(2) \hspace{0.5cm}(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\hspace{0.3cm} \land \hspace{0.3cm} (\psi \rightarrow \phi)\hspace{0.3cm} \not\models \hspace{0.3cm} \phi \hspace{0.3cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} \psi $$

Are there logics for which we have either (or both) of $(3)$ and $(4)$?
$$(3) \hspace{0.3cm} \phi \hspace{0.3cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} \psi \hspace{0.3cm} \nvdash \hspace{0.3cm} \hspace{0.5cm}(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\hspace{0.3cm} \land \hspace{0.3cm} (\psi \rightarrow \phi)  $$
$$(4) \hspace{0.3cm} \phi \hspace{0.3cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} \psi \hspace{0.3cm} \not\models \hspace{0.3cm} \hspace{0.5cm}(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\hspace{0.3cm} \land \hspace{0.3cm} (\psi \rightarrow \phi)  $$

In such logics the equivalence of two formulas $\thinspace \phi, \thinspace \psi \thinspace$ (represented by $\leftrightarrow$) would come apart from their being derivable from one another.

In which setting might such a logic be desirable?

---

Edit: Would it be correct to think of such a logic as a logic in which $\rightarrow$ is not a partial order, but rather a pre-order $\textit{with respect to the $\equiv$ relation}$, where $\equiv$ replaces the usual symbol = used in the statement of antisymmetry (see $(iii)$), and where $\equiv$ is a mere notational variant of $\leftrightarrow$ as used above (chosen $\textbf{for clarity}$)? 
That is would it be correct to say that $\rightarrow$ in logics for which (1), (2), (3) or (4) fails is a pre-order in the sense that we have $(i)$ and $(ii)$ but not $(iii)$ (antisymmetry fails)? $\\$

$$(i) \hspace{0.3cm} \vdash \hspace{0.3cm} a ≤ a \hspace{0.3cm} (reflexivity)$$
$$(ii) \hspace{0.3cm} \vdash \hspace{0.3cm} if \hspace{0.3cm} a ≤ b \hspace{0.3cm}and \hspace{0.3cm}  b ≤ c \hspace{0.3cm} then \hspace{0.3cm} a ≤ c  \hspace{0.3cm}(transitivity)$$
$$(iii) \hspace{0.3cm} \nvdash \hspace{0.3cm} If \hspace{0.3cm} a ≤ b \hspace{0.3cm} and \hspace{0.3cm} b ≤ a \hspace{0.3cm} then \hspace{0.3cm} a \equiv b \hspace{0.3cm} (no \hspace{0.3cm} Antisymmetry)$$

Comment: How are $\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$ defined? I need either derivation rules or a semantic definition to think about. Now there are just symbols (not) related to each other ... but obviously these symbols you gave should not have the usual meaning, so, what else? Edit: Thought the same laughing.  ; )

Comment: Do you have any intuition for what you would like $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ to mean (for the semantic case) or how you would prove it/what you could derive from mit (in the syntactic case)? Edit: That is some timing, on an 8 hour old question....

Comment: Your edit suggests a confusion between logical operators and consequence relations. Implication and equivalence are logical operators, not relations. A partial order is a relation, so implication is certainly not a partial order. The consequence relation on the other hand better be a preorder... Maybe it would help if you read the section "Gerhard Gentzen’s sequent calculus" from https://gentzen.wordpress.com/2016/09/03/logic-without-truth/, especially the sentence "Then the sequent itself is interpreted as $[A_{1}]\cap\ldots\cap [A_{r}]\ \subseteq\ [B_{1}]\cup\ldots\cup [B_{s}]$."

Answer (score 2):

There are logic in which there is no conjunction. In that case only only of $\to$ or $\leftrightarrow$ should be there, otherwise conjunction can be defined via $\phi\land\psi:=\phi \leftrightarrow (\phi \to \psi)$.

The study of such logics can be interesting from computational complexity point of view. Deciding tautology for intuitionistic propositional logic can be reduced to deciding tautology for the implicational fragment of intuitionistic (minimal) logic. Deciding tautology for the implicational fragment of intuitionistic (or minimal) propositional logic is PSPACE complete.

---

Regarding the question about semantics definitions for $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ by aphorisme and Mees de Vries, one example of a large class of propositional logics can be derived from an idempotent and increasing operator $\operatorname{op}$:

- $\operatorname{op}(\operatorname{op}(X))=\operatorname{op}(X)$
- $X \subseteq Y \Rightarrow \operatorname{op}(X) \subseteq \operatorname{op}(Y)$

The propositions would be the subsets $X$ with $X=\operatorname{op}(X)$ and operations would be defined by translating logical operations into operation on sets (pointwise...), and applying $\operatorname{op}$ to the result.

For the question at hand, this would translate into whether
$$\operatorname{op}(\operatorname{op}(A^c\cup B)\cap\operatorname{op}(A\cup B^c))=\operatorname{op}((A^c\cup B)\cap(A\cup B^c))$$
This is probably closely related to

- $\operatorname{op}(X)\subseteq X$

i.e. it will in general only be true intensive operators $\operatorname{op}$. (Exercise: Can you show that for intensive increasing operators $\operatorname{op}$ we have $\operatorname{op}(A\cap B)=\operatorname{op}(\operatorname{op}(A)\cap\operatorname{op}(B))$? What about the converse?)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question to make my motivation clearer. I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say "There are logic in which there is no conjunction. In that case only only of $\rightarrow$ or $\leftrightarrow$ should be there, otherwise conjunction can be defined via $\phi \thinspace \land \thinspace \psi \thinspace :=\thinspace (\phi \thinspace \rightarrow \thinspace \psi) \thinspace \leftrightarrow \thinspace \psi$." Or rather, I'm not sure how such logics would be counterexamples to (1), (2), (3) or (4). Could you posssibly explain?

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum They would be counterexamples in the sense that one or both sides of the relation defined in (1), (2), (3) or (4) would not be defined, and hence the relation would fail. Those restricted logics are not uncommon, and I tried to explain why it can be interesting to study them. The other part of my answer might more directly address the question as you intended it, but do those examples count as logic in your book? Note that aphorisme and Mees de Vries asked you more or less this. Not sure what to make of your edit. Maybe you should try to understand that part of my answer.